# Generate many SymPy expressions using the same symbols

Tags: python, sympy

I want to create many (more than 400) SymPy expressions using the same set of symbols.  The expressions would look like:

```
z_1_8 = k1 + k2 + kuni + k4 + k7
z_2_9_0 = k2 + k8 + k1 + k6
z_3_1_10 = k3 + kbi + k2 + k7
```

The names 'z_1_8' would be generated from a list, where each member of the list contains the numbers that name each expression.  Likewise the symbols would also come from a list in which each member contains a list of the symbols as strings - `'k1'`, `'k2'` etc - for each expression to be generated.

```
list_to_generate_expression_names = [[1, 8], [2, 9, 0], [3, 1, 10],...]
list_to_generate_expressions = [['k1', 'k2','kuni','k4','k7'], ['k2', 'k8', 'k1', 'k6'], ['k3', 'kbi', 'k2', 'k7']]
```

What might be a way to do this?

Comment: SymPy variables *have* to be created dynamically (with the `var` function), so you can do things like `k = [var('k%d' % i) for i in range(10)]`.

Comment: Thanks.  My symbols won't strictly be a sequence of k's.  I just edited the question.

Comment: It's generally better to use `symbols` rather than `var`.

Comment: Do you want to generate `sympy.Eq` objects?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.  I'm very new to using SymPy and not very experienced with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming here that every string in your `list_to_generate_expressions` is the name of an object that already exists.  If that's the case, and your lists match up correctly, you can do this:

```
names = ['z_' + '_'.join([str(n) for n in name_nums]) for name_nums in list_to_generate_expression_names]
exprs = ['+'.join(expr_items) for expr_items in list_to_generate_expressions]

for name, expr in zip(names,exprs):
    exec('{0} = {1}'.format(name,expr))
```

Note that this does use `exec`, which should always be used cautiously, but since you're using your own lists it's perfectly safe.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is exactly what I want to do.  Is there any alternative to using exec, just understand what the options are and what it is doing?

Comment: If everything that you're running through exec is something that you know to be safe, then there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: And I think before doing this, to make strings in 'list_to_generate_expressions' names of objects that already exist, I would declare them as SymPy symbols?

Comment: Yes.  If you have a list of strings that you need to be sympy symbols, you can do: `for i in my_list : exec('{i} = Symbol("{i}")'.format(i=i))`

Comment: Instead of `exec`, initializing a dict `z = {}` should allow to use something like `z[name] = sympy.Eq(name, expr)` in the final loop.

Comment: I think you would still need an exec, because `name` and `expr` are just strings.

Comment: You need `exec` if you to actually define Python variable names for all your symbols. But this is probably unnecessary, as you could just keep track of them by some other way, such as a dictionary as ojdo suggests.

Comment: Can you create a `sympy.Eq` object out of strings?  I was under the impression that you can't.